# Azure db users and permissions reporting

Tags: azure, reporting-services, azure-sql-database

I am trying to come up with a solution/tool that can cycle through all our azure db servers and generate a report of USERS/PERMISSIONS for each db. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: what have you tried until now? care to post some code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the SMO library in Azure-SQL to loop through all Azure SQL databases on a logical Azure SQL server as explained [here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3606/automate-retrieving-sql-azure-bacpacs-with-powershell/). You can then run the following query on each database:

```
SELECT DISTINCT pr.principal_id, pr.name, pr.type_desc, 
    pr.authentication_type_desc, pe.state_desc, pe.permission_name
FROM sys.database_principals AS pr
JOIN sys.database_permissions AS pe
    ON pe.grantee_principal_id = pr.principal_id;
```